# Not showing modal popup

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using .net 2.0 and ajax. I am not getting the pop up. What might be the issue.

Code

```
            <act:ToolkitScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server" ></act:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOverlay" style="display:none;" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
        Some informative message: Hello world!
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="clk" OnClick="MyButton_Click" />
    <act:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="mpe"
        PopupControlID="pnlOverlay"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        TargetControlID="MyButton"
        BehaviorID="mpeBehaviorID"></act:ModalPopupExtender>
</div>
```

I am calling mpe.show() in button click.

Comment: what error u are getting?
show the code on button **MyButton_Click**

Comment: I am not getting any errors. When I click the button, nothing happens

Comment: Under button click only mpe.show() has called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may help u.Try this..

.css

```
   .ModalPopupBG
            {
                background-color: #666699;
                filter: alpha(opacity=50);
                opacity: 0.7;
            }
  .HellowWorldPopup
        {
            /* min-width: 200px;*/
            min-height: 150px;
            background: white;
        }
```

This is .aspx code

```
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
        targetcontrolid="HiddenTargetControlForModalPopup" popupcontrolid="Panel1" drag="true" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="HiddenTargetControlForModalPopup" style="display:none" />

    <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Add product to list" onclick="btnsubmit_Click"/>

<asp:panel id="Panel1" style="display: block;width:550px;" runat="server">
    <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
      Some informative message: Hello world!
    </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Let me try it and will get back to you

Comment: maybe, not sure,have u seen any javascript error after button click

Comment: Yes, 'Sys' is undefined, Type is undefined

Comment: Toolscriptmanager is enough na..in place of scriptmanager ?. As I am not getting scriptmanager tag I used toolscriptmanager tag.